# Java DOM Transformer - XML creation doesn't replace apostrophe and quotes in the final xml

Tags: java, xml

I'm trying to create an XML and return it as a response to the caller based on the input.

The transformer works as expected for most parts, but it doesn't convert apostrophe and quotes to their XML equivalent. Below is the code I'm using

```java
DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

// root elements
Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
Element rootElement = doc.createElement("template");
doc.appendChild(rootElement);

/* Adding attendant ID */
Element line = doc.createElement("line");
line.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("----&----<------>------'-----\"--------"));
Attr Attr1 = doc.createAttribute("Attr1");
Attr1.setValue("attribute value 1");
line.setAttributeNode(Attr1);
Attr Attr2 = doc.createAttribute("Attr2");
Attr2.setValue("attribute value 2");
line.setAttributeNode(Attr2);
rootElement.appendChild(line);

// write the content into xml file
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);

// Output to String
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);
transformer.transform(source, result);
String strResult = writer.toString();

//return escapeXml(strResult);
System.out.println(strResult);
```

Resulting output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<template>
    <line Attr1="attribute value 1" Attr2="attribute value 2">----&amp;----&lt;------&gt;------'-----"--------</line>
</template>
```

Expected Result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<template>
    <line Attr1="attribute value 1" Attr2="attribute value 2">----&amp;----&lt;------&gt;------&apos;-----&quot;--------</line>
</template>
```

Initially I thought could escape those character before sending it as input to transformer, but it replaced all the ampersand to their equivalent `"&amp;"`. If I replace the apostrophe or quotes after the final XML is created, it replaces attributes as well.

I'm thinking we could solve this in 2 ways

1. I could transform the `& , < , > , ' , "` before adding to node and transformer ignores it
2. Give explicit directions to transformer to convert `' , "` them to their XML equivalent.

Currently I'm unaware of how to achieve these. Could someone help me on this or if a better solution to create a valid XML would hugely be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: _If I replace the apostrophe or quotes after the final XML is created, it replaces attributes as well._ Sounds like your "replace" code is wrong. Can you [edit] your question and post the code you use to replace `'` with `&apos;` and `"` with `&quot;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want quotation marks and apostrophes to be escaped? XML doesn't require them to be escaped (except in attributes where they conflict with the attribute delimiters). The serializer knows what it's doing: trust it.

Comment: At the moment it's working well for my use case, the quotation and apostrophes were some of the edge cases which i wanted to test before it goes out there. Thanks